# shell write to file without using last command status

Tags: shell

If I have the following command

```
do_stuff -pram somepram
```

and then typically I do the following to get the status

```
if [ $OUT -eq 0 ]; then
    # do some stuff
else 
    # do other stuff
fi
```

However, I need to write the output of my do_stuff command to a file.

So the command looks like

```
do_stuff -pram somepram 2>&1 | tee someFile
```

Which means the result of `$?` will be the exit code on `tee` and no the command proceeding it.

Is there another way to write to a file that doesn't interfere with this or allows me to obtain the exit code

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 also http://shell.cfajohnson.com/cus-faq-2.html#Q11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command exit status is unrelated to the output it produces.  If the command is well behaved, then you can write:

```
if do_stuff -pram somepram > someFile
then
    : OK - it worked
else
    : Oops - it failed
fi
```

The error messages go to standard error still.  The standard output goes to the file.  You can even check whether the output file is empty on success, treating an empty file as a failure, but if the command is well-behaved, that won't be necessary.

If the command is ill-behaved, then all bets are off.  If at all possible, file bugs and get it fixed so that it returns a reliable exit status.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using `tee`, you can do this at the top of your Bash script:

```
set -o pipefail
```

Then the exit status of the pipeline will be non-zero if any of its stages is non-zero.